# Increasing radio button height is causing issue in Mozilla browser

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I need to increase the size of radio buttons. it's working fine in all the other browsers except Mozilla Firefox. It's blurring the radio buttons.
 [image]

I tried to add `-moz-appearance: none;` css property and style it. but it is returning following result 
[image]

Won't be able to get the control of outer-line. is there any way to fix this issue.

Created fiddler [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ualGFQX5MG5jbBwkbAw9?p=preview) (Please check it in mozila) I am using Mozilla 47.0.0

Comment: On my machine, Firefox 53.0.3 does not scale the radio button. Increasing `width` and `height` only increases white space around the radio button.

Comment: You can make custom radio by using css.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the radio buttons (and checkboxes) using pure CSS as below which work in any browser. You can customize as per your UX. If your radio buttons are of different style you can go for background-image (for label) styling instead of pseudo elements.

Don't forget using id-for combination to group radio and label.

```css
input[type="radio"]{
  display:none;
}
input[type="radio"]+label{
  position:relative;
  margin-right:10px;
}
input[type="radio"]+label::before{
   content:'';
   display:inline-block;
   width:14px;
   height:14px;
   vertical-align:middle;
   border:1px solid #545454;
   border-radius:100%;
   margin-right:4px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked +label::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:#545454;
  border-radius:100%;
  left:3px;
  top:5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="radio1"/>
<label for="radio1">Option 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="radio2"/>
<label for="radio2">Option 2</label>
```